# Retrieve template parameter from base non-template class pointer

Tags: c++, templates, vector, casting

I have a container template class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Container : public IElement
{
  ...
  void createElement();

  std::vector<T *> container_;
};

template <typename T>
void SwXmlContainer<T>::createElement()
{
  container_.push_back(new T());
}
```

The `IElement` can be a empty class for this example.

Then, I have another class `Element` and some other classes that inherit from it:

```
class Element : public IElement
{
  ...
  std::vector<IElement *> childrens_;
};

class ElementA : public Element
class ElementB : public Element
```

As you can see, `Element` can store both objects of `Element` and `Container` in `childrens_` vector.

My question is when I try to cast a `IElement *` from `childrens_` back to a `Container`, like this:

```
Container<Element> * container = static_cast<Container<Element> *>(childrens_[0]);
```

You can assume that a `Container` will always have a `Element` inside (can be `ElementA`, `ElementB`, etc).

Now, lets assume that `childrens_[0]` have a `Container<ElementA>`, using the casted `container` variable, I try to create a new `ElementA` inside the `container`:

```
container->createElement();
```

The problem is that this will instantiate a `Element` object, and not an `ElementA` object.

So what I don't know is how to instantiate a `ElementA` from it. I can anticipate that when I cast the container from the `childrens_` vector I don't know that type of parameter he contains (`ElementA` or `ElementB`), so I can't cast directly to it, therefore I thought that casting it to the base class would resolve it, but it doesn't.

Now, if this is not possible, there is some other solution to my problem?

What I want is to have `Elements` (`ElementA` and `ElementB`) and `Containers` which contains more `Elements` inside in a single vector (it can be 2 vectors if needed, but one vector needs to accept various `Container` with diferent types of `Elements`).

Comment: It's a very weird data structure, but one way to deal with your problem is to have a non-template `IContainer` inheriting your `IElement` with a `virtual createElement() = 0` which is overriden by templated `Container<T>`.

Comment: Having `createElement` is wrong. All polymorphic base classes should be abstract (you won't read this rule of thumb in many places but trust me it's useful). If you make `Element` abstract you immediately see that `createElement` cannot be written at all.

Comment: Rostislav, thanks! that is exactly what I needed, now it works great. I know the structure is weird and is far from the best way to do what I need, but unfortunately there is some restrictions imposed by the company so it needs to be this way. Anyway, You can put your solution as a answer and I will make it the correct one.